# ¿Cuál es el significado del himno "Grato es decir la historia"?

Tags: traducción

¿Qué quiere decir en inglés esta frase?

> Grato es decir la historia; El que la sabe ya Parece que de oirla Sediento aun esta.

Bing Translate sugiere:

> Pleasant is to say the story; The one who knows it seems that hear thirsty even this.

Comment: Pleasant is to say the story; The one who knows it seems thirsty to hear it again

Comment: "Pleasant is telling the history; He who knows it already seems to be still thirsty to hear it"

Comment: Jck: así como está planteada, la pregunta no cumple los requisitos para el sitio. Sería bueno editarla por algo del tipo: "He visto esta frase, Bing me lo traduce como X pero la parte Y y Z no las acabo de entender". Si no, se trata de una mera traducción al inglés que no tiene cabida en un sitio sobre el español.

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que el himno era en inglés inicialmente. Dice así:

> I love to tell the story
>   For those who know it best
>   Seem hungering and thirsting
>   To hear it like the rest

Es parte de un himno cristiano.  El significado es un poco diferente de lo que citas, pero la idea corresponde.